# Spivak, Ch. 24, "Uniform Convergence and Power Series": Understanding statement of Theorem 6

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, power-series, uniform-convergence

I've been reading Chapter 24, "Uniform Convergence and Power Series" of Spivak's *Calculus*, and towards the end of the chapter there is the following theorem which I have a few questions about.

> **Theorem 6** Suppose that the series
>
> $$f(x_0)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_0^n\tag{1}$$
>
> converges, and let $a$ be any number with $0<a<|x_0|$. Then on
> $[-a,a]$, the series
>
> $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\tag{2}$$
>
> converges uniformly (and absolutely). Moreover, the same is true for
> the series
>
> $$g(x)=\sum\limits_{n\to\infty} na_nx^{n-1}$$
>
> Finally, $f$ is differentiable and
>
> $$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n\to\infty} na_nx^{n-1}$$
>
> for all $x$ with $|x|<|x_0|$.

Let me go through this result in my own words.

The series in (1) is an infinite series of numbers. The sequence being summed is $\{a_nx_0^n\}$, and it is summable by assumption. **Do we call a power series evaluated at a certain $x_0$ a power series as well?** Is the expression in (1) a power series?

Then we prove that on $[-a,a]$ the power series $(2)$ converges absolutely (when we evaluate it at any $x\in [-a,a]$), and also uniformly when we view it as a sum of functions. **Is this correct?**

**Why did this theorem not just state that $f(x)$ converges absolutely for any $x$ in $(-|x_0|,|x_0|)$ and converges uniformly on this interval?**

Comment: to your last question, consider $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n$ at $x=1$ converges, but not at $x=-1$. The question in between follows from comparison test. If you are familiar with the root test and/or ratio test you can see why the series with $na_n$ converges.

Comment: @OliverDíaz The theorem states that if a power series converges for some $x_0\neq 0$, then we know that it converges uniformly on any (ie, every :)) interval $[-a,a]$ with $0<a<|x_0|$. Is this not equivalent to stating that it converges on any interval $(-|x_0|, |x_0|)$?

Comment: It is not equivalent unless you add the an adjective: "... it converges on any compact subinterval in $(-|x_0|,|x_0|)$." If you are familiar with the root test, you can work out better arguments yourself that will tell you among other things why $\sum_nna_nx^{n-1}$ converges in $I:=(-|x_0|,|x_0|)$ and uniformly in any compact subinterval of $I$.

Comment: The convergence may not be uniform in the open interval $(-x_0,x_0)$. Consider series for $\log(1+x)$ and $x_0=1$.