# Spivak, Ch. 24, "Uniform Convergence and Power Series": Understanding what happens when we multiply two power series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, power-series

I've spent a bit longer than expected on a particular topic of Chapters 23 and 24 of Spivak's *Calculus*. The topic is how to analyze a product of infinite series. [I've asked about this before (and subsequently, after more thought, tried to answer that question myself)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575040/if-a-n-and-b-n-are-absolutely-summable-why-is-the-arrangement-of-te/4575186#4575186).

The current question is about what happens when, in Chapter 24, we try to multiply two power series.

Towards the very end of Chapter 24 there is a section that I will transcribe below interspersed with my comments. My question is if my understanding of the steps involved is correct.

> We are now in position to manipulate power series with ease. Most
> algebraic manipulations are fairly straightforward consequences of
> general theorems about infinite series.
>
> For example, suppose that $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and
> $g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$, where the two power series
> both converge for some $x_0$. Then for $|x|<|x_0|$ both these infinite series also converge and
>
> $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty
>  b_nx^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (a_n+b_n)x^n$$
>
> So the series $h(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (a_n+b_n)x^n$ also
> converge for $|x|<|x_0|$, and $h=f+g$ for these $x$.

In my words, summing two power series that converge for $x$ in a certain interval means we get another power series. This new power series converges for any $x$ in that same interval because it can be written as the sum of two power series that converge for any $x$ in that interval.

Then he writes

> The treatment of product is just a little more involved. If
> $|x|<|x_0|$, then we know that the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty
>  a_nx^n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$ converge absolutely.

For the record, we know this because of [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574642/spivak-ch-24-uniform-convergence-and-power-series-understanding-statement).

> So it follows from Theorem 23-9 that the product
> $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \cdot \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty
>  b_nx^n$ is given by
>
> $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_ix^ib_jx^j\tag{1}$$
>
> where the elements $a_ix^ib_jx^j$ **are arranged in any order**. In
> particular we can choose the arrangement
>
> $$a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x+(a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0)x^2+...$$
>
> which can be written as
>
> $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n, \text{ for }
>  c_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}\tag{2}$$

That is, we can write the product of the two infinite series in any arrangement of the terms in the resulting sum, and we can choose to use one particularly prominent sum, the Cauchy product in (2).

Hence, we can state that

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \cdot \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n$$

Let me recall here the cited Theorem 23-9

> **Theorem 23-9** If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converge absolutely, and $\{c_n\}$ is
> any sequence containing the products $a_ib_j$ for each pair $(i,j)$
> then
>
> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cdot
>  \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

In summary, here is my take on what all of this boils down to. Theorem 23-9 is the main result. Given that two power series converge for a particular $x_0$, we therefore can be sure that those power series converge absolutely for values of $x$ such that $|x|<|x_0|$. Thus we can apply Theorem 23-9 to these series to conclude that the limit of any infinite series containing terms $a_ib_j$ for all possible pairs $(i,j)$ and in any order will converge to the same number: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n \cdot
 \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_nx^n$.

And it seems that particular prominence is given to one of such infinite series containing such terms: the Cauchy product.

Comment: Due to uniqueness of power series coefficients, the Cauchy product is the unique way to write the product as a $\textit{power series}$. The motivation is the question: "If we know the power series for $f$ and $g$, what is the power series of $fg$?"

Comment: @Mason Unique? I'm surprised I didn't see this term used, or that I didn't notice this. Are you saying then that a power series that is composed of terms $a_ix^ib_jx^j$ but does not arrange them in the order of the Cauchy product is not equal to $\sum a_n x^n \sum b_nx^n$?

Comment: @evianpring: start with polynomials and remember how they were multiplied in high school. In general $(\sum_na_nx^n)(\sum_nb_nx^n)=\sum_nc_nx^n$ where $c_n=\sum^n_{k=0}a_kb_{n-k}$. That that can be done is due to the stability of the power series due to (1) absolute convergence and thus, (2) rearrangements.

Comment: Baby Rudin has (surprise!) a nice proof of the uniqueness theorem for power series. I am sure Spivak does it too but I don't remember exactly where in his book it is.

Comment: The uniqueness assertion is that if $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ on a ball containing $0$, then $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. This can be proved by differentiating the power series $n$ times and evaluating at $x = 0$.